# How can I make these divs move under each other with page responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a row of divs with images within them that looks like this:

[image]

And when I change the page size, essentially what it will look like on mobile devices the divs begin to fall below each other like this:

[image]

Which is amazing because it's exactly what I want. But I have another row of divs that look like this:

[image]

But when I change the page size, this set of divs don't fall under each other like the other divs. They're just cut off by the page so essentially these divs are not mobile responsive. Can anybody help me with have to get these second set of divs responsive like the first set?
Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="extras">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid flex">

            <div class="block text-center">
                <img src="http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/socialmed.png" width="155" height="auto" max-width="100%"/>
            </div>

            <div class="block text-center">
                <ul class="aboutli">
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">FAQ's</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Work With Us</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Privacy Policy<br></a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" img src="http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DrinkawareRed.png" href="https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/"><div id="drinkaware"></div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="block text-center">
                <div id="words">
                    <p class="become">become a driver</p>
                    <p class="driver-para">As an ever evolving new start up we'll constantly be looking for friendly drivers to join the team, so If you'd be interested in  join our team click the button below to see the available opportunities we have available.</p>
                    <input type="submit" id="driver-btn" value="FIND OUT MORE" onclick="location='http://mysite/join-the-team/'"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="block text-center">
                <img src="http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/testimg.png" width="200" height="auto"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#extras {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.block {
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
#words {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
#linksdrinks {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 238px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul.aboutli {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none !important;
  line-height: 0.8cm;
}
#drinkaware {
    width: 156px;
    height: 50px;
    display:list-item;
    background-image: url('http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DrinkawareRed.png');
    background-size: 150px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    vertical-align: top;
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
#driver {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.become {
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.driver-para {
    font-size: 13px;
}
#driver-btn {
    color: #fd0e35;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fd0e35;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
}
#driver-btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #fd0e35;
}
#open24 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/open247.png');
    background-size: 250px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .flex {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. Write your below css in media query

```
@media (min-width:767px) {
div.block {
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
.flex {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This does work, thank you. But is doesn't align them in the centre. Rather in an unorganised way.

Comment: You can try "justify-content: center;" for inner content

Answer (score 0):

Also for cross browser support `display: inline-flex;` is now `display: flex;`

be sure to use

http://autoprefixer.github.io/